# Cannot access a file in multi-thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, file

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());  
           // multiple sw.WriteLine
    }
}
```

In spite of the fact that FileShare is set to "None", an Exception is launched "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
I'm in Multi-thread context and the file is not written/read somewhere else.

Why ?

Comment: I'd assume the file has already been opened by someone else before you even get to the using block.

Comment: Are you trying to open the same file on multiple threads?

Comment: @BrokenGlass No. @Daniel Yes but it's supposed to be one thread after the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to write to a file from multiple threads - this is not possible without some sort of synchronization to ensure the file is closed before attempting to write by another thread.

As for [`FileShare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) set to `None` - this means that multiple threads are *not* allowed to share the file, so of course you get a sharing violation exception.

> None - Declines sharing of the current file. Any request to open the file (by this process or another process) will fail until the file is closed.

Comment: However, I didn't understand MSDN correctly about FileShare.None. Thank you ;-)

Comment: @Spilarix - You need to ensure the file is _closed_ before you can write to it from another thread.

Comment: The using statement doesn't close the file ?

Comment: @Spilarix - It should, but if you have a second thread trying to write _before_ the end of the `using` block has been reached...

Answer (score 5):

[FileShare.None](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) is saying "Don't let anybody share this file" - the opposite of what you want.  I believe you were after [FileShare.ReadWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx).

That being said, I recommend avoiding this issue altogether.  It would be much better to have your writing handled in a single thread, and use a producer/consumer approach to requesting an entry to be added.

The `BlockingCollection<T>` class works very well for this type of scenario.  You can have multiple threads each add a new "entry" to the collection, and a single thread running in the background that just calls `GetConsumingEnumerable()`, and writes out all of the values.

Comment: I keep this solution in mind but I can't use it for this project. Thank you !